# How to refresh current line in Oracle APEX Interactive Grid?

Tags: oracle-apex

For refresh current line in Intractive Grid I have previously used JavaScript code:

`apex.region("MY_GRID").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").invoke("selection-refresh");`

It's work fine in APEX 20.2. But in APEX 21.1 it stopping working for new lines! For old lines (after refresh IG by *Action->Data->Refresh* or after full page refresh by F5) for 21.1 it's still works. But for new line (after *"Add Row"* and *"Save"*) only in 20.2!

| Action | APEX 20.2 | APEX 21.1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Click *"Add Row"*, click *"Save"*, start Ajax-process to update this row, start `invoke("selection-refresh")` | + | - |
| Press F5, start Ajax-process to update this row, start `invoke("selection-refresh")` | + | + |

> **Note**: Why I need Ajax-process here? Because I have some modal window that updates data in row. And after close this window I need refresh current line in Interactive Grid. I use *Dynamic Action* "Dialog Closed" and "Execute JavaSctiopt Code".

I suspect that the problem is that no data in "selected row array" (in 21.1). Grid method `getSelectedRecords()` return 0 in 21.1 after *"Add Row"* and *"Save"*. I try to add row in selected rows, but it didn't help:

```js
let grid = apex.region('MY_GRID').widget().interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid");
let rec = grid.model.getRecord(lineId);
grid.setSelectedRecords([rec]);
let selRecCount = grid.getSelectedRecords().length;
conosle.log('selRecCount:', selRecCount ); // selRecCount == 1 in 20.2, and selRecCount == 0 in 21.1
apex.region("MY_GRID").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").invoke("selection-refresh"); // works in 20.2 only
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following construct:

```
let grid = apex.region("IG_ID").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid");
let rec = grid.model.getRecord(apex.item("P892_CUR_ROWID").getValue());
grid.setSelectedRecords([rec]);
grid.model.fetchRecords(grid.getSelectedRecords());
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Doesn't works for me. Even after `grid.model.fetchRecords(grid.getSelectedRecords())` still `grid.getSelectedRecords().length == 0`. Also I tried callback: `grid.model.fetchRecords(grid.getSelectedRecords(), () => { getIGPackageLinesActions().invoke("selection-refresh"); });`,  but that didn't help either, callback is never called.